# Error #1452 when trying to insert foreign key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I'm trying to insert a foreign key in my table A (in phpmyadmin):

ALTER TABLE A
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_B)
REFERENCES B(id_B);

But I get the error:

## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-edf_534aa1'>, CONSTRAINT `#sql-edf_534aa1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_B`) REFERENCES `B` (`id_B`))

Table A has id_A as primary key and Table B has id_B as primary key. Both table have innoDB as storage engine and the columns id_B in table A and id_B in table B have the identical types.

Whats in wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do the two tables have data in them already? If so, adding the constraint will check that it actually holds true. Check that all id_b values in table A exist in table B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table A likely links to an invalid id_B:

There exists an id_B in table A that does not exist in the table B id_b column.

Comment: That's right. There was a value in column id_B in Table A that doesn't exist in column id_B in Table B. Thanks!